# How do I access the `BLOG_SLUG` string?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

When I type `{{ settings }}` on a template and open it with Mezzanine, it shows me `{u'MEZZANINE_ADMIN_PREFIX': u'grappelli/'}`. I'm trying to access `settings.BLOG_SLUG`, but cannot get that setting to appear in the template. Here's a small snip of what my template looks like.

```
{% load mezzanine_tags keyword_tags i18n %}
{% block main %}
  {{ settings }}
{% endblock %}
```

How do I get my template to display the string stored in `setting.BLOG_SLUG`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass settings.BLOG_SLUG from your view than you would be able to display it in html.
for example you have written line settings.py file like
BLOG_SLUG = 'something'
than you can retrieve it in your view as
SETTINGS.BLOG_SLUG
and you can pass it from your view to html

Comment: Is there no way to get it from the core settings file? I have to make a copy of it in my app’s settings file?

Comment: yes you can import your all settings with
from django.conf import settings
Then you can access your setting.varibale_name you want to access